# How to get Avg Date in SQL Qry

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the Average Date in sql and am not sure how to do this.  I have the following fields:

```
ID   Date1             Date2                   Date3
1    05/04/2012        08/09/2012             07/02/2012
```

i want to add another column that shows the Average Date for the ID number 1.  I have done only average number but never done average Date.  thanks

Comment: If you can tell me what is the average date of 05/04/2012, 08/09/2012, 07/02/2012, then i show you the query.

Comment: Hmm... how exactly would you define an 'average date'?

Comment: i believe i asked the wrong question what i needed to ask was how to calculate the median date for these 3 dates.

Comment: Can you tell what is the median of this 3 dates (05/04/2012, 08/09/2012, 07/02/2012) ?

Comment: Are these US or UK style dates?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan As far as I'm concerned, an average date is any form of sensible date, weighted according to the dates combined. Representing date as a number since some epoch and taking an average of those numbers would achieve that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like this, which casts the date to a `float` and then takes the average:

```
select t.id, t.date1, t.date2, t.date3, src.AvgDate
from yourtable t
inner join 
(
  select id, cast(avg(date) as datetime) AvgDate
  from
  (
    select id, cast(cast(date1 as datetime) as float) date
    from yourtable
    union all
    select id, cast(cast(date2 as datetime) as float) date
    from yourtable
    union all
    select id, cast(cast(date3 as datetime) as float) date
    from yourtable
  ) x
  group by id
) src
  on t.id = src.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f31ce/4)

Since your date values are across multiple columns, I performed an `unpivot` or `union all` to get the values in a single column first then take the average of that value.

Here is another example of using the `UNPIVOT` function:

```
select t.id, t.date1, t.date2, t.date3, src.AvgDate
from yourtable t
inner join 
(
  select id, cast(avg(date) as datetime) AvgDate
  from
  (
    select id, cast(cast(date as datetime) as float) date
    from yourtable
    unpivot
    (
      date
      for col in (date1, date2, date3)
    ) unpiv
  ) x
  group by id
) src
  on t.id = src.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f31ce/2)

Comment: bluefeet, thank you so much for your help.  I am getting this error when i try to run it: Explicit conversion from data type date to float is not allowed.

Comment: @user1858332 then you will have to perform two casts, one to datetime and then the second to float. See my edit

Comment: @bluefeet: How do you do this with `DateTime2`?  It generates "Explicit conversion from data type float (/bigint/int) to datetime2 is not allowed." error when you try to `Cast` it to a `Float`.

Comment: @Tom Without seeing all the info it would be difficult to answer, I'd recommend [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include all the details, along with sample data and the query you've attempted to get an exact answer.

Comment: @bluefeet: I believe my q. is within the scope of O.P.'s q *as worded* (even though it may not have been his *intent*).  He did not specify whether he was using `DateTime` or `DateTime2` either of which could've been used given his q (and `DateTime2` was available since SS 2008 years before O.P.'s q).  Your solution *assumed* he was using the `DateTime` possibility.  I'm simply asking for a solution to cover the `DateTime2` possibility also (not just on principle but because that is the need I currently have).

Comment: @Tom If you have a `DateTime2`, then convert/cast it to a datetime, then cast as a float/etc. That should solve the issue [see this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46e53/1/0).

Comment: @bluefeet: Ah!  Duh!  But of course, you'd lose the precision and range (all prior to year 1753) benefits of `DateTime2` vs. `DateTime` which are prolly the 2 biggest and also at the same time the 2 least likely needed which begs the question why use it when you lose so much.  I'm actually trying to answer a more generic q. of the pros and cons of each when the loss of implicit / easy conversions to floating-point numeric (# of days) for addition / subtraction / "age" (vs. `DateDiff`) / `Avg` calcs con is a big one at least for us.  Thx!

Comment: @Tom As I said, you can go ahead and ask another question on the site if you have something specific you're looking for. I answered the question in 2012 and while you say that the OP didn't specify datetime or datetime2, they accepted the answer provided. If you're trying to answer a more generic question, then post one on the site.

Comment: @bluefeet: You already answered my q. (the solution to O.P.'s q as it applies to `DateTime2` also vs. just `DateTime`).  I was just adding commentary (for you and anyone else) to explain *why* I wanted to know (which was the larger q. of the pros / cons of `DateTime2` vs. `DateTime`).  My interest in this q. was how its a's could contribute to answering that larger q., and I've gotten my a.  I was not expecting any additional a's or even clarification of existing a's from you.  Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, date1, date2, date3
,Cast(
(cast(date1 as Float) + cast(date2 as Float) + cast(date3 as Float))/3
as Datetime) as AvgDate
from yourtable
```